# Android: Processing video and sound on phone

Tags: android, video, audio

I want to merge a sound file and a video file (remove the sound from the video file and replace it with my own sound) and this should happen on the phone. 
I have done this through ffmpeg, but I can't do that now.

Any help appreciated,
10x,
Danail

Comment: hi did you get answer for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your only hope of doing that will involve using the [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) to create a C/C++ library, perhaps leveraging ffmpeg logic. Or, perhaps find an `ffmpeg` ARM port and run it via `Runtime.exec()`.

In reality, I am skeptical that a phone CPU will do this very quickly.